# Naked singularity and AdS/CFT

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, black-holes, string-theory, ads-cft

I am a bit confused about the status of naked singularities that appear in black hole physics and more so in the context of AdS/CFT. Here is what I know about this in brief.

For a charged Reissner-Nordstrom (RN) black hole naked singularities appear for $Q \gt M $, where $Q$ is the total charge and $M$ is the mass of the black hole. They are valid solutions to Einstein's equations. But due to some 'physical' reasons people don't like them much. Because if they are not covered by 'horizons' observers can interact/communicate with them. Even there exists 'cosmic censorship conjecture' (which is not a theorem as the name suggests) that tells us singularities must be 'covered' by horizons. This conjecture has been shown to hold under some 'reasonable assumptions'.

I have the following confusions :

1. How seriously should we take the cosmic censorship conjecture? By this what I mean is these are all classical concepts and the full quantum theory of gravity is supposed to resolve the singularity. Then is not it something put in by hand to get rid of the singularity which might be due to just incompleteness of classical theory?
2. Is there something like some artificial infinitely rigid wall that people have used to avoid interaction/communication of observers with the singularity.
3. Finally, and most importantly, what is the status of these type of singularities in AdS/CFT set ups? I am not aware if they are used in these type of applications . Some references will be highly appreciated. I recently found this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2800) where the authors take $M=0$ limit of RN AdS black hole and claim this to be dual to the confinement phase with quark matters (or, hadronic phase). I have no idea how well established/accepted this is though.

Comment: This might help answer the 3rd question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156756/what-happens-at-the-center-of-a-black-hole-according-to-holographic-theory/159251#159251

Comment: @brucesmitherson thanks for your comment. As far as I see those are all BHs with event horizon. But I am interested mainly in BHs without horizon.